# Android Studio Emulator White Bar in Middle of Screen

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

So I made my own Custom Skin for a android emulator with Android studio but now I have a white bar in middle of my screen: [image]

layout

```
parts {
  device {
    display {
      width 1409
      height 3195
      x 0
      y 0
    }
  }
  portrait {
    background {
      image back.webp
    }
    foreground {
      mask mask.webp
      cutout emu01
    }
  }
}
layouts {
  portrait {
    width 1571
    height 3332
    event EV_SW:0:1
    part1 {
      name portrait
      x 0
      y 0
    }
    part2 {
      name device
      x 81
      y 68
    }
  }
}
```

I edited everything I needed didn't I?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, the background of the mask has to be this:

[image]

And not this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to have a pixel error in your mask.webp file :)